# Initial GET takes longer than get TF.exe

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I'm downloading files with this code:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection 
    = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://local.DevOps-TFS/tfs/resourceCollection"));

Workspace ws 
    = Workstation.Current.GetAllLocalWorkspaceInfo()[0].GetWorkspace(tfsTeamProjectCollection);

Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
ws.Get(new string[] { "$/REPO/file.cpp" }, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.OneLevel, GetOptions.GetAll);
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
ws.Get(new string[] { "$/REPO/file2.cpp" }, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.OneLevel, GetOptions.GetAll);
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

This works well, except that the first GET takes 9 seconds, the 2nd get takes 0.05 seconds.
It doesn't matter what files and how many I'm getting, the first file ALWAYS takes significantly longer than the following gets.

The weird thing is: getting the file with the TF.exe works way faster, the first get is as fast as the other ones.

```
tf vc get $/REPO/file.cpp /force
```

I've debugged into the TFS-API Source-code and the problem is the moment the API waits for the rest-api call to finish. I assume that there's a problem with the authentication, but I couldn't figure out what exactly is wrong.
I've also debugged into the TF.exe to see how they authenticate, but I didn't find anything specific and they're using the same code as above. But somehow the rest-api call tarted from the TF.exe finished much faster than the rest-api call from my application.

We're using TFS version 16.
Any suggestions on how to continue?

Comment: Maybe you can use tf.exe in your C# application to get the files instead of use the Get method of the api.

Comment: No, using the TF.exe is sadly not an option. The code above is just an extract of a large application using the whole set of the available TFS apis.

Comment: I understand, keep using TFS API, but only in the get operation use tf.exe